# CRON vs While loop

Tags: cron

I have a Twitter bot that checks for new tweets every 60 seconds... Would setting up CRON to run the script every minute be better than putting the script in a (24/7) while true loop with sleep(60), or no?

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out for yourself - you don't need our help. (And you've not given us enough to answer your question anyway!)

You seem to be asking if it is more efficient to use **polling**, or **interrupts**. The answer is almost inevitably **interrupts** are more efficient. Of course you need to use an API that will pass these interrupts to your program.

Answer (score 1):

I like CRON jobs but you have to think:

1. If the program errors, it will retry and possibly error every minute.
2. The extra wear on the SD card from log entries
3. The slight set up time every minute (CPU cycles used to cost money when I started)
4. Changing programs require you to stop the CRON job
5. Debugging can be harder if the background job fails

On the other hand:

1. Will you get garbage collection issues with long running code?
2. How do you start the program if it fails?
3. You have to remember to start the job each reset unless you start it with a reboot CRON job
4. You can change the 60 second delay easier than a CRON job if you need to speed up the enquiry
5. It’s best to make sure anything / everything is closed before the delay so a reset has less chance to corrupt files

TBH - I’ve never liked delays in the UK due to BST/GMT changes catching some code out and find one off jobs easier to debug interactively than sit around for delays.  If I do have delays in code I normally have a ‘warp speed’ flag for debugging that cuts the delays down :)